# how do i delete characters in a string/text of a textbox?

Tags: asp.net, textbox, substring

I have an asp.net 4 textbox control that has it's text being dynamically populated by some java script. A Google Maps call to be exact. It's giving me mileage from 1 point to another. When the text displays, it shows " 234 mi" I need to get rid of the "mi" part of this text because the text is being converted to an Int32 Updating a table in my DB.

Basically I can only have an INT. Nothing else in the text box. How do I get rid of the "mi" at the end of the text?

Thanks
C#
EB

Answer (score 1):

On the postback, before you save it you could:

```
var saveValue = Int32.Parse(tbTarget.Text.Replace("mi", string.Empty).Trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) works also:

```
String leftPart = TxtMileAge.Text.Substring(0, txt.IndexOf(' '));
int mileAge = int.Parse(leftPart);
```

This retrieves the part of the `String` in the range of *0 - indexOfWhiteSpace* and converts it to an `int`

**Edit**: Since the value can have decimal places (as you've commented), you need to parse it to `double`, round it and then cast it to `int`:

```
var txtEstDistance = new TextBox() { Text = "40.2 mi" };
String leftPart = txtEstDistance.Text.Substring(0, txtEstDistance.Text.IndexOf(' '));
double distanceMiles = double.Parse(leftPart, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
int oDdstanceMiles = (int)Math.Round(distanceMiles, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. I tried your code. Changed it just a bit to: <code> String leftPart = txtEstDistance.Text.Substring(0, txtEstDistance.Text.IndexOf(' '));
int oDistanceMiles = int.Parse(leftPart);</code>  I am getting this error: "Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length"    Also, the number that is being auto- populated  is "40.2 mi" what i really need is just 40 or any round number that shows up. Clipped off at the decimal point. Am I formatting the subtring wrong? Thanks.

Comment: `40.2 mi` would not result in an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, that would happen only if there's no white-space at all. You cannot parse `40.2` to an `int` (`FormatException`) since it has decimal places. So you need to parse it to a `double` and then round it. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your working with a variable length of chars (say someone enters miles instead) then your must do a foreach against the string (an array of char) and check isnumeric on each char.